# My function validation does not work on added row

Tags: javascript

I have a function where my input type="number" data-id="weight" checks whether the user typed a divisible by 5 or not. It is perfectly working on my current row but when i add a new row/s, it is not working. Is there anything i missed? I provided my snippet below. Thank you everyone.

To try it. Please type on the weight column a number that is not divisible by 5, then you'll see the error. Add row and do the same, you will not see the error. My target is my function to work with added rows too.

```js
$("#addrow").on('click', function() {

  let rowIndex = $('.auto_num').length + 1;
  let rowIndexx = $('.auto_num').length + 1;

  var newRow = '<tr><td><input class="auto_num"  type="text" name="entryCount" value="' + rowIndexx + '" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input name="lightBand' + rowIndex + '" id="auto"  value="" class="form"  type="number"  /></td>"' +
    '<td><input data-id="weight" name="weight' + rowIndex + '" type="number" placeholder="not working divisible by 5" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input id="wingBand" name="wingBand' + rowIndex + '" type="number" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow' + rowIndex + '" name="removerow' + rowIndex + '" value="Remove"/></td>';

  $("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);


});

// divisible by only 5
const inputer = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-id="weight"]');
inputer.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (input.value % 5 !== 0) {
      alert('not valid');
      input.value = 5;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1" id="applicanttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div class="row">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>LB#</th>
        <th>Weight#</th>
        <th>Wingband #</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row_0">
        <td>
          <input id="#" name="#" class="auto_num" type="text" value="1" readonly />
        </td>
        <td class="labelcell">
          <input value="" class="hehe form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" />
        </td>
        <td class="labelcell">
          <input data-id="weight" name="weight1" type="number" placeholder="Working divisible by 5" />
          <input data-id="weight" name="weight1" type="number" placeholder="Working divisible by 5" />
        </td>
        <td class="labelcell">
          <input name="wingBand" class="hehe form-control" type="number" />
        </td>
        <td class="labelcell">
          <input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow0" name="removerow0" value="Remove">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
  </div>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <button type="button" id="addrow" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Add Row</button>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: When the page is loaded, the browser add the event listener on existing elements. So you have to add manually the same event listener after new table row has being appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the event handler for the `change` event not being fired for dynamically created objects.

When you create an the event handlers like this:

```
const inputer = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-id="weight"]');
inputer.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', () => {
        ...
    }
});
```

The handler is only mapped for elements that exist *when you first run the code*.  That means any subsequently created dynamic elements **will not** cause the event to fire.

Instead, use the following syntax to create the event which will catch dynamically created elements by using their selector (`input[data-id="weight"]`):

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[data-id="weight"]', function(e) { 
  if ($(this).val() % 5 !== 0) {
    alert('not valid');
    $(this).val(5);
  }
});
```

I've removed the other code you had previously that tried to bind the event handler.  You don't need to do it that way with jQuery.

Seen here in a working version of your snippet:

```js
$("#addrow").on('click', function(){ 
            
            let  rowIndex = $('.auto_num').length+1;
            let  rowIndexx = $('.auto_num').length+1;
        
            var newRow = '<tr><td><input class="auto_num"  type="text" name="entryCount" value="'+rowIndexx+'" /></td>"' +
                            '<td><input name="lightBand'+rowIndex+'" id="auto"  value="" class="form"  type="number"  /></td>"' +
                            '<td><input data-id="weight" name="weight'+rowIndex+'" type="number" placeholder="not working divisible by 5" /></td>"' +
                            '<td><input id="wingBand" name="wingBand'+rowIndex+'" type="number" /></td>"' +
                            '<td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow'+rowIndex+'" name="removerow'+rowIndex+'" value="Remove"/></td>';
        
            $("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);               
        
        
});

// divisible by only 5
$(document).on('change', 'input[data-id="weight"]', function(e) { 
  if ($(this).val() % 5 !== 0) {
    alert('not valid');
    $(this).val(5);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table class="table table-bordered" border="1" id="applicanttable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>
       <tbody>
          <div class="row">
             <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>LB#</th>
                <th>Weight#</th>
                <th>Wingband #</th>
                <th>Action</th>
             </tr>
             <tr id="row_0">
                <td>
                   <input id="#" name="#" class="auto_num" type="text" value="1" readonly />
                </td>
                <td class="labelcell">
                   <input value="" class="hehe form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto"/>
                </td>
                <td class="labelcell">
              <input data-id="weight"  name="weight1"  type="number" placeholder="Working divisible by 5" />
                <input data-id="weight"  name="weight1"  type="number" placeholder="Working divisible by 5" />
                </td>
                <td class="labelcell">
                   <input  name="wingBand"  class="hehe form-control" type="number" />
                </td>
                <td class="labelcell">
                   <input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow0" name="removerow0" value="Remove" >
                </td>
             </tr>
          </div>
       </tbody>
       </div>
       <tfoot>
         <tr>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <button type="button" id="addrow" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Add Row</button>
         </tr>
        </tfoot>                                        
   </table>
```

Comment: Perfect working with clear explanation. I've learned a lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Add `change event listener` after adding the table row. Modified the above code as below:

```js
$("#addrow").on('click', function(){ 
            
            let  rowIndex = $('.auto_num').length+1;
            let  rowIndexx = $('.auto_num').length+1;
        
            var newRow = '<tr><td><input class="auto_num"  type="text" name="entryCount" value="'+rowIndexx+'" /></td>"' +
                            '<td><input name="lightBand'+rowIndex+'" id="auto"  value="" class="form"  type="number"  /></td>"' +
                            '<td><input data-id="weight" name="weight'+rowIndex+'" type="number" placeholder="not working divisible by 5" /></td>"' +
                            '<td><input id="wingBand" name="wingBand'+rowIndex+'" type="number" /></td>"' +
                            '<td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow'+rowIndex+'" name="removerow'+rowIndex+'" value="Remove"/></td>';
        
            $("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);    
            const list = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-id="weight"]');
            const input = list[list.length - 1];
            console.log(input)
            input.addEventListener('change', inputValidation);
        
        
        });
        
const inputValidation = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value % 5 !== 0) {
      alert('not valid');
      e.target.value = 5;
    }
}
        
           // divisible by only 5
 const inputer = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-id="weight"]');
inputer.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', inputValidation);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table class="table table-bordered" border="1" id="applicanttable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>
       <tbody>
          <div class="row">
             <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>LB#</th>
                <th>Weight#</th>
                <th>Wingband #</th>
                <th>Action</th>
             </tr>
             <tr id="row_0">
                <td>
                   <input id="#" name="#" class="auto_num" type="text" value="1" readonly />
                </td>
                <td class="labelcell">
                   <input value="" class="hehe form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto"/>
                </td>
                <td class="labelcell">
              <input data-id="weight"  name="weight1"  type="number" placeholder="Working divisible by 5" />
                <input data-id="weight"  name="weight1"  type="number" placeholder="Working divisible by 5" />
                </td>
                <td class="labelcell">
                   <input  name="wingBand"  class="hehe form-control" type="number" />
                </td>
                <td class="labelcell">
                   <input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow0" name="removerow0" value="Remove" >
                </td>
             </tr>
          </div>
       </tbody>
       </div>
       <tfoot>
         <tr>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <button type="button" id="addrow" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Add Row</button>
         </tr>
        </tfoot>                                        
   </table>
```